# How can I use VB.Net extension methods in a C# project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a legacy VB.Net class library that includes some extension methods, one of which is roughly this:

```
Namespace Extensions
    Public Module OrmExtensions

        <Extension()>
        Public Function ToDomainObjectCollection(ByRef objects As OrmCollection(Of OrmObject)) As DomainObjectCollection
            Return objects.AsQueryable().ToDomainObjectCollection()
        End Function

        <Extension()>
        Public Function ToDomainObjectCollection(ByRef objects As IQueryable(Of OrmObject)) As DomainObjectCollection
            Dim doc As New DomainObjectCollection()
            For Each o In objects
                doc.Add(o.ToDomainObject())
            Next
            Return doc
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

To use these extensions in VB I just have to import Extensions.OrmExtensions. I have another project, which is in C# that depends on the VB one with the extensions and I can't get them to work.  OrmExtensions isn't available and simply using the namespace VBProject.Extensions doesn't make the extensions available.

There are multiple projects that depend on the VB project and ideally the extensions should be available to all of them.

I've done a fair bit of googling but haven't been able to turn up anything about actually using VB extension methods in C#. I assume the issue is that they're required to be in a Module, but I haven't been able to confirm that.

I'd rather not duplicate the extension methods everywhere they're required(especially in our unit test project, which is in C#).

Comment: You should extend `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: What happens if, in C# with the correct using, you type `OrmExtensions.` and look for the methods? How do they appear? Do they look like valid extension methods?

Comment: compile those extension method as an external library and then add a reference to that library from your c# projet

Comment: @TimS. the method is simply not available.

Comment: @SLaks i would disagree. If you need to extend IQueryable then that would be acceptable. Perhaps you need to explain further?

Comment: @SimonHalsey: He doesn't need to extend IQueryable.  All he does is iterate.

Comment: @SimonHalsey His point is that since I'm just iterating over the collection, I can simply extend IEnumerable and get it for free on IQueryable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be using `ByRef`.

VB.Net (apparently) supports extension methods on `ref` parameters; C# (rightfully) does not.

A `ByRef` (`ref` in C#) parameter allows the method to assign a new instance to the variable or field passed by the caller.
They should rarely be used.

Comment: (And the fact that they're being used here possibly indicates a lack of understanding of the meaning of ByRef, which should be addressed.)

Comment: @EricJ.: Well for one thing the value of `objects` isn't changed in either of these methods. Why would you want it to be `ByRef`? And what would it *mean* for it to be `ByRef` with a changing value? What would happen if you called it on the result of a method call, for example?

Comment: @EricJ.: The callsite would either implicitly pass `ref` (allowing the method to unexpectedly change the caller) or make a hidden temporary variable (possibly breaking the method)

Comment: @JonSkeet ByRef was used (perhaps naively) to attempt to avoid the potentially expensive creation of a copy of a large collection.

Comment: @JustinEdwards: Yup, that suggests you don't understand what `ByRef` means (or rather, what `ByVal` means for reference types). It would be worth reading my C#-based article on the topic - the same principles are the same with VB: http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html